# INDEX MATCH with >= and <= as criteria not returning correct value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following code that I am using to find an address when entered and return column E on Sheet2:

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$A$1:$N$7755,MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!A:A=$C$4)*('Sheet2'!B:B=$I$4)*('Sheet2'!F:F=$G$4)*('Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$7755<=$B$4)*('Sheet2'!$D$2:$D$7755>=$B$4),0),5)
```

On Sheet2, A is the street name, B is the Zip, F is the City, C is the lowest address for the block, and D is the highest address of the block.

```
A       B       C   D   E   F
1ST ST  12345   100 399 N   City1
1ST ST  12346   100 299 N   City2
1ST ST  12347   101 522 N   City3
1ST ST  12347   600 899 E   City3
```

When I use this however, searching for 650 1st St, City3 12347 will return N instead of E (trying to get column 5).

This seems to be a problem specifically with the >= and <= section of the formula, but I'm not sure what.  Does anyone see what is causing the problem?

Comment: Question - You're using full columns (`B:B`, `F:F`) and a limited range (`C2:C7755`) in the `Match()` part. What happens if you make those ranges the same size? (Either don't use full columns, which is likely preferable, or switch `C` and `D` references to the full column).

Comment: @BruceWayne I hadn't even noticed I did that.  I changed it to full columns and it appears to be working correctly.  So if you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with the ranges used in `INDEX/MATCH`.  AFAIK, the ranges should all be the same size.

There are two ways you can solve it, pick your choice of the below.

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$A$2:$N$7755,MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!A$2:A$7755=$C$4)*('Sheet2'!B$2:B$7755=$I$4)*('Sheet2'!F$2:F$7755=$G$4)*('Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$7755<=$B$4)*('Sheet2'!$D$2:$D$7755>=$B$4),0),5)
```

or

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$A:$N,MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!A:A=$C$4)*('Sheet2'!B:B=$I$4)*('Sheet2'!F:F=$G$4)*('Sheet2'!$C:$C<=$B$4)*('Sheet2'!$D:$D>=$B$4),0),5)
```

(Personally, I recommend ***not*** using full column references, as doing so - especially with more than two columns - can slow your formula/worksheet down)

Comment: Making the ranges the same worked!  I chose the full column option because the information I'm searching in is likely to expand in the future and I'll be passing it off to someone else not as experienced in Excel.  That way they won't have to go and edit each of the separate formulas that use the Index Match to use the new column numbers (currently 15 different columns are being returned).

Comment: +1. Just a clarification, using full column references, in itself, implies no performance penalty that I'm aware of when using `INDEX` or `MATCH`. The performance penalty in this case is caused by comparing the full column references to a value, e.g. `A:A=$C$4`.

Comment: @BruceWayne It was more intended for the person posting the question, as I realized you probably already knew that :)

Comment: @bubbajake00 - Totally understood.  One further note, I have spreadsheets like that too, but I know for a fact that I'm extremely unlikely to go past, say row 50,000.  Therefore, I still don't use full column references, I just set it up with a range like `A2:A50000`.

Comment: @BruceWayne True, I could preemptively set it.  I may go ahead and do that, though probably to 100,000 just to be safe.